# when i use the --pylab flag with ipython, the builtin function 'any' no longer works properly with a generator expression. anyone know why?

Tags: python, matplotlib, built-in

here's the code that shows what's weird here. with `--pylab`:

```
sys.version
Out[208]: '2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.1 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'

any(x for x in xrange(61))
Out[210]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000001AEC4C60>
```

without `--pylab`:

```
sys.version
Out[1]: '2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.1 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'

any(x for x in xrange(61))
Out[3]: True
```

what's going on here? `pylab`, wth are you doing?

Comment: short answer is that you should never use `pylab` unless you're only going to read in a file, plot it, look at the plot, and then exit python.